# Regarding Windows Application Development And NPAPI plugin

Tags: visual-c++, npapi, firebreath

I am planning to make an application that monitors the websites visited by the users and performs some calculations on that.

So for every website that is opened,I developed a google chrome extension that will send the URL to a NPAPI plugin.

The problem is with the second part.Is it possible for a NPAPI plugin to pass the information it received from the extension to another application.I want a 2 way communication between my application and the NPAPI plugin so that depending on the processing performed by the application,the NPAPI plugin informs the extension to change the URLS it should send.

PS-I am using firebreath to develop the NPAPI plugin if that makes it easier to answer my question.

I would really like some ideas as to how this can be implemented.I am new to programming.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NPAPI plugins have unrestricted access to the local machine, so your plugin is running its code like any other application. So what you're looking for is actually a way for two processes to communicate, AKA [Inter-Process Communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). There are quite a few ways of doing that, you can find some [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372198/best-way-for-interprocess-communication-in-c). The most appropriate one depends on your actual need, but when searching, don't let the NPAPI context bother you. You're just trying to get two processes to talk.

Answer (score 0):

Shared memory is quite simple to use. Since you're new to programming ,I think this is the way to go. You can find an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366551%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)