# Setting permission for shared memory created by boost

Tags: c++, permissions, boost-interprocess

We open a boost shared memory that was created by another process like this

```
  boost::interprocess::managed_shared_memory segment(boost::interprocess::open_only, "SharedMem");
```

But if the process that created the shared memory was a root user, then the process reading it, if it was a normal user, will fail with the reason as:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::interprocess::interprocess_exception'
what():  Permission denied
```

What should i do to avoid this? that is to give permission to the shared memory to all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at the **shared_memory** [constructor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/shared_memory_object.html#id971608-bb), it takes a [permissions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/permissions.html) object. `boost::interprocess::permissions::set_unrestricted` is probably what you are looking for

```
void set_unrestricted();
//Sets permissions to unrestricted access:
//        A null DACL for windows or 0666 for UNIX.
```

According to [this](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/4350), it was added in 1.45 version

Comment: and in what version was it implemented?

Comment: is there anyway to include it in 1.42? it is the version available for ubuntu repository and i dont have the rights to update it manually by installing the binaries.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a sample code snippet, to grant unrestricted permission to shared memory during creation

```
boost::interprocess::permissions  unrestricted_permissions;
unrestricted_permissions.set_unrestricted();

shared_mem = new managed_shared_memory(open_or_create, name.c_str(), size, 0, unrestricted_permissions);
```