# boost::interprocess ubuntu exception on creating managed shared memory object

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost, boost-interprocess

I am newbie in boost. I am trying to use shared memory to communicate between processes using boost.

It works perfectly on my windows using vs2010 with 4 processes sharing memory with a manager. The manager initiates the shared memory mechanism before the other processes are launched.

However, I am getting an `interprocess_exception` on Ubuntu 14 running inside VirtualBox. I am using boost 1.58 and intel compiler. Same code works on windows using vs2010.

```
struct shm_remove 
{
  shm_remove() { shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory1"); }
  ~shm_remove() { shared_memory_object::remove("MySharedMemory1"); }
} cleaner;

// exception occurs in the next line 
managed_shared_memory sharedMemSegment = managed_shared_memory(boost::interprocess::create_only, "MySharedMemory1", 65536);
```

exact error : 
"terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::interprocess::interprocess_exception'   what():  No such file or directory

Changing to `boost::interprocess::open_or_create` did not work.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: if you use open_or_create do you get the same error in the exeption?

Comment: Yes , same exception , same message "No such file or directory"

Comment: While debugging boost I've found out that it uses FILESYSTEM_BASED shared memory and it failes in opening the file name for my shared memory. Using sudo when running my app doesn't help , is there another shared mem mechanism , not file based ?

Comment: non-name based only when you fork the processes I guess. have you checked those things? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30850686/reasons-a-user-might-not-be-able-to-open-a-shared-memory-object-on-linux-systems usually for me it has been problems with /dev/shm on a virtual machine sometimes.

Comment: Try the [XSI](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.sharedmemory) SYSTEM 5 shared memory for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use any "`/`" in the `shared_memory_object` name.

### Why

The "`/`" character confuses boost, because on macOS the shared memory objects are stored in the file system, in a temporary folder called `boost_interprocess`.

In macOS 12.6.3 you can find this folder in `/tmp/boost_interprocesses`.